# Why WCF does not destroy the object when I close the client application without calling "Close" method on the client side?

Tags: wcf, destructor

I have a net tcp WCF service as follows

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class AVService : IAVService
    {
        static int _numberofInst = 0;
        public AVService()
        {
            ++_numberofInst;
            Console.WriteLine("Number of instances "+_numberofInst);
        }
        ~AVService()
        {
            --_numberofInst;
            Console.WriteLine("Number of instances " + _numberofInst);
        }
        public void Foo(){}
    }
```

When I create an object on the client side as follows

```
AVService client = new AVService();
client.Foo();
```

The constructor is called, but when I close the client application without calling close mehotd, the destructor does not been called? why? does this mean the service object still works on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - if you don't explicitly dispose of your client, the server will "hang around" for a while (since you specified [PerSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx) mode).

It will eventually time out (specified by the `InactivityTimeout` setting on the binding configuration), and will be destroyed. But that could take some time (several minutes to several hours, depending on your settings).

```
<bindings>
   <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="NetTcp_Reliable" receiveTimeout="00:20:00">
         <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="false" 
                          inactivityTimeout="00:15:00" />
      </binding>
   </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Therefore, it is the best practice to **always dispose of your client before closing the app**.

Comment: Good, but inactivityTimeout put into the client configuration file so this means the configurations on the client side will be sent to the server side when the connection established?

Comment: You can and should also put it into your server config! Whichever is shorter will "win", if the session is still alive.